# Plotting two variables indirectly dependent on each other

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, evaluation, histograms

I have the following system of linear ODEs for "i" number of species "c" migrating in "j" number of habitats:

```
eq1 = Table[D[c[i, j, t], t] == q - (s[i] + d[j]) c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 1}];

eq2 = Table[D[c[i, j, t], t] == s[i] c[i, j - 1, t] - (s[i] + d[j]) c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 2, 9}];

eq3 = Table[D[c[i, j, t], t] == s[i] c[i, j - 1, t] - d[j] c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 10, 10}];

initCon = Table[c[i, j, 0] == 0,{i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 10}];

sol = DSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, initCon}, Flatten@Table[c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 10}], t];

(* for i=5 and j=10 *)
h = 4;
hd = 4;
m = 0.5;
d[0] = 0.05;
di = 0.2;
q = 100000;
s[i_] := (m + m i)/2;
d[j_] := d[0] + (di*j)/(hd + j);
```

so I can evaluate the population size and plot it as a histogram against j

```
BarChart[Evaluate[Table[Sum[c[i, j, t], {i, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 10}] /. sol /. t -> 100]
```

Now, I have a function f which also depends on j,

```
f= 1000 (j/j+h)
```

I want to plot population size as histogram against f now, given the relationship between f and j.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: once you have computed `Total` (you should not use a capital `T` for your own symbol by the way ) it is a function of `t` only.  As there is no more `j` in the expression the last bit doesn't make any sense.  Perhaps you meant to just sum over `i` ?

Comment: @george2079 I have made some changes in the question for better understanding. Please go through them and help me!

Comment: @Xavier I have made some changes in the question for better understanding. Please go through them and help me!

Comment: it would be best if you provide a minimal working example. In your code `c`, `s` and other functions are not defined. Anyway, I'm not sure I understand your problem, but can't you just invert your last equation expliciting `j` as a function of `f`, and than use `BarChart` to plot against that?

Comment: @glS  tried that... but doesn't work for non-integer values of j and specially if you have a non-linear relationship between j and f values of j

Comment: @glS the required definitions are there. The stuff at the bottom needs to be evaluated before the stuff at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it makes sense: Just add your `f` to each table item: (added parenthesis required, else you just have `1+h` )

```
 Evaluate[Table[{1000. (j/(j + h)), 
       Sum[c[i, j, t] /. (First@sol), {i, 1, 5}]}, {j, 1, 10}] /. 
            t -> 100]
```

> {{200., 517802.219885}, {333.333, 449216.620639}, {428.571, 
>     382758.770615}, {500., 322594.11367}, {555.556, 273802.994}, {600., 
>     297371.4}, {636.364, 1.34096*10^6}, {666.667, 
>     1.7341*10^7}, {692.308, 2.1090*10^8}, {714.286, -2.762*10^72}}

Your totals vary by many orders of magnitude, so a simple plot of this is meaningless.

Here is a Log plot..  note even on the log scale the last point is really big.

```
ListPlot[Evaluate[
  Table[{1000. (j/(j + h)), 
     Log@Abs@Sum[c[i, j, t] /. (First@sol), {i, 1, 5}]}, {j, 1,10}] /. t -> 100]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I realize how stupid the querry was .)